# code for finding the size of a folder in remote machine using directory info class- ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need the code for finding the size of a folder in remote machine(server).
I tried using directory info class , but its ending up in error"The UNC path should be of the form \server\share".
I tried different combinations , but the error appears to be same.
CODE IN SOURCE FILE IS AS FOLLOWS

```
strPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RetryFolderPath"].DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(strPath);
          long size = DirSize(dInfo, true);
          long totalSize = 0;
          foreach (FileInfo fi in dInfo.GetFiles())
           {
              totalSize += dInfo.Length;
              xlWorkSheet.get_Range("E" + iIndex, misValue).Cells.Value = Decimal.Round(size / mb, 2).ToString() + "mb";
           }
```

**PATH GIVEN IN CONFIG FILE IS AS FOLLOWS**

```
<add key="RetryFolderPath" value="\\machineipor server name\folder_path"/>
```

Comment: The path did not come through. Remember that \ is an escape character in strings so you may need to turn it into \\ which will generate a \ in the resultant string.

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick: Not in web.config. It's just XML.

Comment: Can you print the output of `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RetryFolderPath"]`?

Comment: It's an XML configuration, and the value is still a string so you need to try \\machineipor server name\\folder_path. The string rules still apply. It's an XML Configuration file, but it's a string attribute.

Answer (score 0):

guess your property is actually empty, due to the fact you are using `ConfigurationManager` while on ASP.NET. The right class for ASP.NET is [`WebConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
strPath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RetryFolderPath"]
```